k-th Derivative of Legendre Polynomial is an orthogonal set
I have to show that the k-th derivative of the Legendre Polynomial $P_{i+k} , i \in \mathbb{N_0}$ is a set of orthogonal Polynomials with the weight function $\rho _k :(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}:x \rightarrow \left(1-x^2 \right)^k$.
My idea was to use the Rodrigues Formula
$P_i (x)=\frac{1}{2^i i!}\frac{d^i}{dx^i}\left((x^2–1)^i\right)$
and show that
$2^{i+k}(i+k)!\langle P^{(k)}_{i+k},q^{(k)}\rangle_{\rho_k}=0$
with a $q \in \Pi_{i+k-1}$,
but the expression gets very messy quickly if i try to use partiell integration.
Any Tipps on how to prove this?
